# Is there a way to save a ton of images offline to be send to the server later?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, progressive-web-apps

My user will need to fill out multiple forms and take multiple photos during the day while he is offline. When he is connected to the internet, the application will send all these photos. Is there any way to store such a large amount of information using a PWA?

I know that local storage won't allow me to store it all. There is a possibility of using IndexedDB, but I doubt that it stores such a large amount of data. Is there a way to reference the photos saved on the device only when I'm sending the data? For example, instead of saving the physical copy of the files, I could store the directory that he's saved and only look for these files when I'm sending them to the server.

Comment: IndexedDB is probably your best bet. Most browsers will prompt the user when you reach some threshold, but you can store far more than local storage. You cannot store the files on the filesystem.  You can also use the FileSystem API, but this is non-standard: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API/Introduction

Comment: The FileSystem API would be perfect for me, if it wasn't non-standard. Thank you. I'll try to use IndexedDB.

Comment: You should take a look at this https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/offline-for-pwa